# sqlserver - computing and getting efficiciency matrix from period data

Tags: sql, sql-server, logic

I need to get efficiency data :

```
create table #tbl( userid int,workid int,  workstartday int, workendday int, workyear int)

and data
insert into #tbl(userid, workid, workstartday,workendday,workyear) 
values(1,1,2,5,2017),(1,2,3,5,2017),(1,3,4,8,2017)
```

Startday and Endday is the work days internal

Output needed, that shows user efficiency over days

i.e.,

```
user 1 - 1st day - 0 work
user 1 - 2nd day - 1 work
user 1 - 3rd day - 2 work 
user 1 - 4th day - 3 work
user 1 - 5th day - 3 work
user 1 - 6th day - 1 work
user 1 - 7th day - 1 work
```

Thanks in advance for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a temp table with all the days. Than count the works for each day.

```
;with days_rte as
(
    select min(workstartday) [day],max(workendday) [lastDay]
    from #tbl
    union all
    select a.[day]+1, a.lastDay
    from days_rte a
    where [day] < a.lastDay
)

select t.userid,d.[day],count(t.workid) [work]
from days_rte d
join #tbl t on d.[day] between t.workstartday and t.workendday
group by t.userid,d.[day]
```

Comment: Shouldn't the query take also `workyear` into account?

Comment: I can modify the query to take workyear into account, Thanks Peter so this simple and straight solution.

Comment: @Serge I forgot about workyear. I think there should be a separate start and end year. Or ideally use start and end date.